# Properties of component are undefined using class and prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've made use of the class and prototype pattern in JavaScript. I've made a function named `NavigatieButton` and got a constructor of three attributes named `location`, `rotation` and `navigatie`.

In the prototype of `NavigatieButton`, I've maked a function named `init` that must render a "component".

Inside the `render` function I make a new instance of `NavigatieButton` using code below:

```js
var navBtn = new NavigatieButton('0 0 0');
```

But if I call `init`, the properties `location`, `rotation` and `navigatie` are undefined.

Here you could find my code I've made.

```js
"use strict";

function NavigatieButton(location) {
  this.location = location;
}

NavigatieButton.prototype.init = function() {
  var element = document.createElement('a-entity');
  element.setAttribute('location', this.location);

  // Here I'm adding some other nodes to the `element` variable.

  return element;
};

(function() {
  
  function render() {
    var el = document.createElement('div');

    for (var i = 7; i--;) {
      var navBtn = new NavigatieButton('0 0 0');
      var comp = NavigatieButton.prototype.init();

      el.appendChild(comp);
    }

    console.log(el);
  }

  render();
})();
```

Open the console of your browser to see the logged data. Below you could find a snippet of the logged data.

```html
<div>
  <!-- 7 thimes this code: -->
  <a-entity location="undefined" rotation="undefined">
    <a-image src="./assets/images/navigationOuterCircle.png"></a-image>
    <a-image src="./assets/images/navigationInnerCircle.png" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-image>
  </a-entity>
  <!-- Till here -->
</div>
```

What's wrong with my code? Why I've always undefined instead of my input?

**PS 1:** I'm following this article: [3 ways to define a JavaScript class](https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) *(see heading 1.2)*.

**PS 2:** I'm using [aframe](/questions/tagged/aframe) to create WebVR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
  var comp = NavigatieButton.prototype.init();
```

you must call `.init()` with the object you just created:

```
  var comp = navBtn.init();
```

The `.init()` function will be found on the prototype, and when it's called the correct way the value of `this` will be a reference to the `navBtn` object you created.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling init function of `NavigatieButton` constructor directly which is not a newly created object.

Use `navBtn.init();` instead of `NavigatieButton.prototype.init();`